# Characterizing totally bounded sets in Banach spaces with Schauder Basis

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

This is Exercise $6.10.182$ in Bogachev's Real and Functional analysis textbook

> Let $\{e_n\}$ be a Schauder basis in a Banach space $X$. Prove that $K
>  ⊂ X$ is totally bounded precisely when for each $\epsilon > 0$  there
> is $N_{\epsilon}$ with $\sup\limits_{x\in K}  \|\sum \limits_{k
>  =N_{\epsilon} }^\infty c_k (x)e_k\| \leq {\epsilon}$ where $x= \sum \limits_{k =1 }^\infty c_k (x)e_k$

The issue I have with this exercise is the following:

Let $\{e_n\}$ be the standard Schauder basis (it takes the value of $1$ at the n-th coordinate position and $0$ otherwise) in the separable sequence space $\ell^1$ and consider the set $K = span(e_1,e_2) = R^2$. Now given any $\epsilon$ take $N_{\epsilon} = 3$ then it readily follows that $ \sum \limits_{k =3 }^\infty c_k (x)e_k = 0$ for all $x$ in $K$ and hence satisfies the condition for total boundedness. However we know for a fact that $R^2$ is not totally bounded so I'm not sure what is missing here. Of course the same argument could be made for $R^n$ instead of $R^2$. The way I see it, the above condition is true if we also add that $K$ is a norm bounded set on top of satisfying the above condition (if $K$ is norm bounded its projection onto a finite dimensional subspace will be totally bounded and it's easy to prove the theorem from there). Am I correct or am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are correct.  The example of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ shows that it is necessary to assume $K$ is bounded.